# Does Prawn gem support Arabic Language?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I'll create a pdf report in Arabic Language, but the letters is separated and in reverse order, I use the following code to generate a pdf file

```
class InstitutesPdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize(institute)
    super()
    font(Rails.root.join("app/assets/fonts/arial.ttf"))
    @institute = institute
    text "Institute ID : #{@institute.id}"
    move_down(30)
    text "Institute name : #{@institute.name.mb_chars.to_s}"
  end
end
```

when I change the last line to

```
text "Institute name : #{@institute.name.mb_chars.reverse.to_s}"
```

the word letters shows in proper order but still separated

I use rails 4 and prawn version '1.1.0'

Answer (score 1):

I had developed a gem to fix this problem particularly to be used with prawn that was refactored by Sinan into this project:

https://github.com/staii/arabic-letter-connector

So in console:

```
gem install arabic-letter-connector
```

Then in code:

```
require 'prawn'
require 'arabic-letter-connector'
Prawn::Document.generate("arabic.pdf") do
  text_direction :rtl
  font("/path/to/arabic/font.ttf") do # For example: http://www.amirifont.org/
    text "مرحبا يا العالم".connect_arabic_letters
  end
end
```

As you have mixed text and might not want to use :rtl, a workaround would be to reverse the string yourself before printing into the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I was trying to print Arabic words via RMagick

I did it by using [connect_arabic_letters](https://github.com/staii/arabic-letter-connector) to connect them, and then used .reverse to reverse the characters (You might not have to do it)

FYI: This doesn't work well if the words are decorated (Tashkeel/Harakat)