# Arabic word in rails prawn shows reverse order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, prawn

When I try to create a pdf in Arabic Language, I'm getting the letters in reverse order.

I use the following code to generate a pdf file.

```
 note_section = {content: "#{order_item.try(:notes).try(:connect_arabic_letters)}" , 
  size: 8, 
  font: "app/assets/fonts/ufonts.com_arial-unicode-ms.ttf", 
  text_color: "313131"}
```

Expected text is:
[image]

In prawn it looks like:

[image]

Gem version => Prawn version:2.2.2  Rails version:5.1.6

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This might be related to your issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651908/does-prawn-gem-support-arabic-language

Comment: Also, could you provide the version of the gem you are using, and a small snippet of your code?

Comment: @RodrigoVasconcelos I'm using prawn (2.2.2) and  (Rails 5.1.6)

Comment: `note_section = {content: "#{order_item.try(:notes).try(:connect_arabic_letters)}" ,  size: 8, font: "app/assets/fonts/ufonts.com_arial-unicode-ms.ttf"}`